# OAUTH2 flow for authentication across clients

Tags: web-services, rest, oauth-2.0, openid-connect, google-oauth

I seem to be royally confused, somehow OAUTH2 or it's newer more stringent subset OpenID Connect just don't click in my head...

My application is a RESTFUL service that has no Web UI whatsoever.

Several clients are using it ( from both web and mobile apps )
My service should store per user data.

Now we want to allow the clients to authenticate via common providers that support OAUTH2 ( e.g facebook,google etc.. )

They should be able to handle the authentication in their application and just give my service an identity token that i can verify as in "Ok this is a valid user token that was signed by a valid authority" and can use to associate the users data on my side with it. ( and return to the clients of course at a later time )

How to achieve this with OAUTH2 ? Which flow to use ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Identity Token is OIDC (OpenID Connect) thing, OAuth2 is about Authorization. verifying (authenticating) End user Identity is the main objective of OIDC.

In your use case: usually after the end user authenticated by OP (mostly using Implicit flow), client/RP (relaying Party) will receive Identity Token, and Access Token, Identity Token is meant for the client, Access token is the token to be used for requesting your protected REST API.

Example: `setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);`

Now your REST API, send the received Bearer/access token (usually JWT format) to OP, if its valid then you apply your permissions/filtration logic.

Maybe this [gist](https://gist.github.com/jawadatgithub/638c11f08ecc0d76b05c) will help you understand the use cases of each flow.

Hope its answer your question.